# the best way to display this jquery data

Tags: jquery

What could be the best way to display this jquery data. I know I can possibly do **$('.Counter').html(count);**

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

.Counter { color: white;background: red; padding:6px; }
</style>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

alert('okay');  
//var Counter = [];
$user = 'nancy';
count = 1;

$('#' + user + ' label.Counter').html(count);
$('#' + user + ' label.Counter').show();


});

</script>
  </head>
  <body> 


<label class="Counter"></label>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's missing a parent element of the label that has the id "nancy" for this to work.

Comment: @matthias_h Thanks for responding. please can you provide a testable example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example of your code. I've added `display:none;` to the CSS of the class `Counter` because otherwise the `show()` method you're using would be unnecessary.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  alert('okay');
  $user = 'nancy';
  count = 1;

  $('#' + $user + ' label.Counter').html(count);
  $('#' + $user + ' label.Counter').show();

});
```

```css
.Counter {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  padding: 6px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nancy">
  <label class="Counter"></label>
</div>
```